# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cookiecutter.main'; 'cookiecutter' is not a package

Tags: python, cookiecutter

I am trying to use the python to create a project from a cookiecutter. I've installed cookiecutter globally (I am not using a virtual environment) on Windows with pip

```
pip3 install cookiecutter
```

I am able to use cookiecutter as a command in GitBash. However, when I try to use it within a python script (based on [these](https://cookiecutter.readthedocs.io/en/0.9.1/advanced_usage.html) instructions), I get:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cookiecutter.main'; 'cookiecutter' is not a package
```

Here is the script file:

```
from cookiecutter.main import cookiecutter

cookiecutter(
    '<redacted>',
    no_input=True,
    extra_context={
      'directory_name': 'bar',
      'file_name': 'baz',
      'greeting_recipient': 'inga'
    }
)
```

What am I missing here?

[edit]
I've also tried this using the Windows standard command prompt, and also in Linux, with virtualenv. The result is always the same.
[/edit]

Comment: Are you using python3 to run the script file?

Comment: the command is simply `python`, but when I do `python --version` it shows as being 3.7.0. That should be sufficient, correct?

Comment: It is definitely using pip and python executables from the same installation

Comment: If the pip3 is not linked for another python3 version then it should be fine.

Comment: If you are simply using python, then `pip install cookiecutter` should be okay

Comment: I tried `pip3 uninstall cookiecutter` and then `pip install cookiecutter`. Unfortunately, the output is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
import cookiecutter
import cookiecutter.main
```

invoke like this:

```
cookiecutter.main.cookiecutter
```